# How to display the JPEG Image directly from byte array (Before saving Image)?

Tags: android, image, sockets, jpeg

I am receiving a jpeg image (Image size: 50KB) from client socket and saving in emulator SD Card. From there I am displaying the jpg image in Imageview. But I want to display the image before saving image on the SD Card because our android appli will receive the continous images from sockets, If I follow receive, save and display method then it will become very slow process, so to increase the speed I want display from ram only. For this I need to save the image array temporarily on the RAM. From there I planed to display and save by using the separate threads. So please guide me how to display the image from byte array.

Note: I am receiving JPEG image from socket, not .bmp or .gif or .png.

Below is my code for receiving the image from tcp socket. (Its working fine)
(Note: This is done in seperate thread, don't try it in UI thread.)

```
                    public byte[] mybytearray  = new byte[310000];
                    private int bytesRead=0;
                    private int current = 0;

                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);  
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept(); 


                   try {

                       myDir=new File("/mnt/sdcard/saved_images");

                        if (!myDir.exists()){
                            myDir.mkdir();
                        }else{
                            Log.d("ServerActivity","Folder Already created" );
                        }

                        String fpath = "/image0001.jpg";
                        File file = new File (myDir, fpath);
                        if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();


                        InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                        current = bytesRead;

                 do {
                      bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
                      if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;

                 } while(bytesRead > -1);

                        bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);

                        Log.d("ServerActivity","Reconstructing Image from array");

                        bos.flush();
                        bos.close();
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        is.close();
                        client.close();
                        serverSocket.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) { 
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
```

Answer (score 10):

Try inserting this code snippet into your code:

```
do {
    bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
    if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
} while(bytesRead > -1);

ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(myByteArray);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
ImageView picture = new ImageView(this);
picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Bitmap, create it from Byte Array,

```
Bitmap bitmap;
bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert byte[] to bitmap.
Try the following

```
ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byte[] array);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
```