# Android How to receive jpg from web Api Call and Display it in ImageView

Tags: android

I have a quick question how to receive a jpg image from a web api call.

```
String result = webApiManager.getBarcode(dataStorageManager.currentUser.CustomerID);
```

This method returns a jpg image but I am unsure how to handle it and display it in an ImageView. Furthermore, what data type is a jpg image and how do I convert it into an image that I can display using an ImageView. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this. Thanks for your time.

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: try creating an inputStream and a ByteArray and then converting it into a bitmap and then displaying it . Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257604/how-to-display-the-jpeg-image-directly-from-byte-array-before-saving-image

Comment: like the webAPI is a Image???

Comment: this method returns a string... not an image.

Comment: I just temporarily put it to receive a string but It returns a JPG

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead of returning the image as a jpg...why not just return the URL to the image and then use AsyncTask in processing it...

It will be easier and faster that way... just my 2cents

Comment: That seems more like pushing the problem around than actually solving it.

Comment: it shouldnt be a problem from this point on...except he doesnt know what he is doing....